# How to dynamically change a background image of a div using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html

- What will be the syntax to change the background-image of body using javascript
- How to fix the error in line `y.style.background = '' + "url(1.jpg) no-repeat" + '';`

Markup :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        body {
            //this is the style for body tag
            background: url("heart.png") no-repeat;
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h3><p id="hello">This Is Heart.</p>
        </h3>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
                var x = document.getElementById("hello"); //this is id of paragraph
                var y = document.getElementsByTagName("body"); //id of background element
                var z = document.getElementById('myImg');
                y.style.background = '' + "url(1.jpg) no-repeat" + ''; //y error what will be the code to replace background-image of div
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try `style.backgroundImage=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the backgorund image of your `body`, you can do this

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(1.jpg)";
document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
//OR
document.body.style.background = "url(1.jpg) no-repeat";
```

**Update**:

`document.getElementsByTagName("body")` returns a collection(like an array) of elements with tag `body`. Since we have only one body we will use `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]`.

See the ***[docs.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbytagname.asp)***

Comment: thanks but why can't we take document.getElementByTagname("body");

Comment: @sandeep_1994. You can. `document.getElementByTagname("body")` returns a collection of elements, so you need `document.getElementByTagname("body")[0]`. However I feel this is the proper way to do it.

Comment: what type of element collection please tell me if i change index to [1]

Comment: @sandeep_1994 . See the update. `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[1]` will return `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is probably (though you might want to add the actual error message to your question) that `getElementsByTagName()` returns an array of DOM elements and not a single one. So if you change to

```
var y = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]; //array will contain a single element
y.style.background = 'url(1.jpg) no-repeat'; //No need for your funky empty string concatenation
```

I think you should be good.

Comment: if i don't use [0] index then it also work then why did u use it

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand. Without `[0]` my solution wouldn't work, and wasn't the lack of `[0]` what was breaking your own code?

Comment: My answer explains why your code was broken and provides a working solution - may I ask what's wrong with it?

Comment: no nothing wrong with it i just wanted to know about index [0] and its functionality

Comment: I see, I was just referring to the fact that you removed the accept mark and haven't upvoted.